# Cómo Mantener procesos trabajando internamente al cerrar el navegador

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, csv, servidor

he creado un script en PHP que me permite cargar un archivo CSV, extraer la data realizar una serie de validaciones, incluso consulto durante el proceso a un archivo externo para que me traiga cierta información al pasarle datos extraidos del Csv, (para lograr todo el funcionamiento del script también me apoyo en Ajax). 
Finalmente la data resultante se inserta en una tabla de Base de Datos(uso MySQL) y conluye el script.

Sin embargo estos archivos CSV podrían poseer muchisimos datos, hasta más de 100mil por archivo, por lo que el proceso de extracción y almacenamiento de los datos en la BD podría tormarle mucho tiempo al servidor. 
Lo que me gustaría lograr es, subir el archivo, poner a trabajar el Script que cree y tener la posibilidad de cerrar el navegador si el proceso se torna largo debido a la cantidad de datos, pero que el script se siga ejecutando internamente en el servidor, así no se interrumpirá todo el trabajo que el script este realizando.

Esto se puede lograr? 
Que sugerencias o ejemplos me podrían dar para lograr obtener ese resultado? 
Podría hacer esto con codigo PHP o debo configurar algo a nivel de servidor para que este tipo de cosas se logren?

Comment: No te sirve ejecutar el script por linea de comando?

Comment: O ejecutar el script desde una tarea CRON

Comment: Por Linea de Comando no me sirve lastimosamente.

Comment: Lo de ejecutar el script por CRON lo consideré debido a que leí en otras preguntas que sugerían esta opción para realizar cosas parecidas pero realmente nunca he utilizado esta herramienta del servidor, no sé que alcance tenga